# How to user surfaceslider with touch control

Tags: pixelsense

I want to use my surfaceslider control inside tagvisualization so that it responds to finger touch when an object is placed, but when I run the program it doesnt moves at all. Can anybody give me pointers (I am new to this sdk).

---

```
<s:TagVisualization x:Class="ControlsBox.TagVisual"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
Loaded="TagVisual_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <!--ProgressBar Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Value=""-->
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBlock1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,6,0,0" Foreground="#FFAA4A4A" />
    <s:SurfaceSlider Width="100" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,50,0,0" Value="60" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="False" Margin="20" Name="mySlider" Maximum="100" Interval="1" ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged">
        <s:SurfaceSlider.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="2"/>
        </s:SurfaceSlider.Effect>
    </s:SurfaceSlider>
    <Ellipse Width="200" Height="200" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="8" Opacity="0.7">
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="12" />
        </Ellipse.Effect>
    </Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Height="196" Width="196" Stroke="AntiqueWhite" StrokeThickness="4" >
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="4"/>
        </Ellipse.Effect>   
    </Ellipse>
    <Label Content="John's Phone" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
        <Label.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="9" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Aqua"/>
        </Label.Effect>
    </Label>

</Grid>
```

---

```
    private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        this.textBlock1.Text = Math.Round(this.mySlider.Value/100,2).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is covering it up so the touch doesn't get to it.   Set IsHitTestVisible=false on the label and anything else you don't want to receive touch input.  Mouse input works the same way.  Tools like "Snoop" are great for debugging issues like this

Comment: I wonder how the slider in the below link is coded. This looks like a glowing slider (probably use of overlapping controls with blurred radius) but what about curve and the big track ??

[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/testxfl.jpg/)